# How to check twitch streamer status(if they are streaming)

Tags: html, twitch, twitch-api

How can I find out if a twitch streamer is live on my website with the press of a button, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you have to use the Twitch Api, you have some research leads [here](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/reference/streams) and [here](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference#get-games) (to check if a streamer is online).

And to Embedding Twitch in your Website, you have [this.](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/embed)

Comment: I found some code that should work but it says that it denied the quest from twitch so I think the problem is that my site is not secure.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid that and use another api?

Comment: The Twitch embed script is `<script src="https://embed.twitch.tv/embed/v1.js"></script>`, I'm not sure you need an https site to use it, but it's sure that the twitch api is the easiest way (that I know) to embed twitch function on your website.